# How to write expression check for null and check for empty value is any shorter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular 8 application.

And I have this expression:

```
  @Input() answer: any;
this.echeqElement.required && (this.answer === null || this.answer === '')
```

So answer is of type any.

But can you write this shorter?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, you probably can, but no, you shouldn't. Prefer explicit code over implicit hacks.

Comment: What do you mean with that? And what is then the solution?

Comment: The solution is to keep what you have. It *works* and it's exactly what you need for this to work. Moreover, it signals your intention very clearly, so it's easy to maintain in the future as well. Finally, it's not even that long - an extra OR is hardly problematic. If you need to repeat this check a lot, then just encapsulate it in a function and you get shorter code.

Comment: Oke, thank you for you answer. I just strive always for the best code. That is way I ask it. Then I can accept your answere.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `!!this.answer`, it will solve the nullcheck incl. empty string.

Comment: But would also catch `0` which could be a valid value.

Comment: Yes, and that is a valid answere. And what about this: (typeof(this.answer !== 'undefined') )

Comment: But so can you improve this?